# Unable to locate tables in Derby database

Tags: java, derby, netbeans-8

I can't work out why the following program is unable to locate tables in my derby database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NdConnect
{
  public final static String SETUP_FILE_PATH = "/AppData/Local/NewdawnTest"; 
  private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:derby:" + "C:/Users/" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + SETUP_FILE_PATH + "db" + ";create=true";
  private static Connection conn = null;
  private final static Properties dbProperties  = new Properties();
  private static PreparedStatement pstmtSelectTxns;   

  public static void connect() {
    try {  
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL  + ";create=true", dbProperties);
      pstmtSelectTxns = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from TXNS");
      System.out.println("Connected OK to " + CONNECTION_URL);   
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
      System.out.println("SQL exception");
      System.out.println("Connected NOK:The connection URL is " + CONNECTION_URL);
      Logger.getLogger(NdConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    } 
  }

  public static void disconnect() 
  {
    try {
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
        System.out.println("0048 NDC OK:DB closed ");  
      }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
      Logger.getLogger(NdConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }
  }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
//   NdConnect nd = new NdConnect();  
   NdConnect.connect();
   NdConnect.disconnect();
//    System.out.println("NdConnect finished");
  }
}
```

The program throws a  SQLSyntaxErrorException:

```
run:
SQL exception
Connected NOK:The connection URL is jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/NewdawnTestdb;create=true
Nov 25, 2018 6:58:42 AM NdConnect connect
0048 NDC OK:DB closed 
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'TXNS' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at NdConnect.connect(NdConnect.java:21)
    at NdConnect.main(NdConnect.java:47)
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'TXNS' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

However the database and table do exist. I have verified this by creating a connection to the database in Netbeans > Services. When I run this command in Services:

```
SELECT * from TXNS
```

the desired table is correctly displayed and the output window returns:

```
Executed successfully in 0 s.
Fetching resultset took 0.016 s.
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0.254 s, no errors occurred.
```

Looking at the properties of this connection via Netbeans services shows the following attribute values:

```
Display name    NewDawn – TEST DB
Database URL    jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NewdawnTest\db
Driver          apache_derby_embedded
Driver class    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

This seems to correspond to the setup I have in the java code example so I don't understand why the code doesn't work.

Comment: where's `pstmtSelectTxns.execute()`? or `executeQuery()`?

Comment: These statements would be included in the code if I could get past this SQL exception. I have five other projects that worked without problems using jdk1.7_ but I have just migrated to a new laptop running jdk1.8_191. Whether or not I implement the prepared statement seems immaterial - the SQL exception is thrown in every situation. In the example I posted Im simply trying to strip down to the bare essentials of connecting successfully.

Comment: Remove `create=true`

Comment: These statements would be included in the code if I could get past this SQL exception. I have five other projects that worked without problems using jdk1.7_ but I have just migrated to a new laptop running jdk1.8_191 and this exception is thrown whether or not I implement the prepared statement. In the example I posted I'm simply trying to strip down to the bare essentials of connecting successfully.

Comment: @user7294900 Removing create=true has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is not the same:

In Netbeans:    `jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NewdawnTest\db`

In Java:        `jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/NewdawnTestdb;create=true`

Change the `CONNECTION_URL` line to:

```
private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:derby:" + "C:/Users/" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + SETUP_FILE_PATH + "/db"
```

Comment: thank you very much, problem solved. A bad miss on my part not picking up on the forward slash.